# Get right sorting over a grouped table in mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by, where-clause

I am currently stuck with following problem:
I have two tables:

```
person
  - uid
  - first_name
  - last_name
mail
  - uid (autoincrement)
  - to_person -> 1:1 relation to person.uid
  - from_person -> 1:1 relation to person.uid
```

How can I get all mails of a person with uid=1, sorted by mail.uid DESC and grouped by person.uid? I tried following:

```
SELECT a.first_name,a.last_name,b.uid
FROM person as a, mail as b
WHERE
  (b.to_user=a.uid OR b.from_user=a.uid) AND
  (b.to_user=1 OR b.from_user=1) AND
  a.uid!=1
GROUP BY a.uid
ORDER BY b.uid DESC
```

It does give me back my exact amount of persons but the ordering to the latest mail does not work.

Anyone can give me an idea what how to solve this?

Thanks, Dominic

EDIT:

here my solution which works if somebody has the same question:

```
SELECT a.uid,a.first_name, a.last_name, b.max, c.tstamp, c.to_user, c.from_user
FROM person a
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT MAX(uid) max, to_user,from_user, IF(to_user=13,from_user,to_user) AS other_user, tstamp
  FROM mail
  WHERE (to_user=13 OR from_user=13) AND deleted=0 AND hidden=0
  GROUP BY GREATEST(to_user,from_user), LEAST(to_user,from_user)
  ORDER BY max DESC) AS b ON b.other_user=a.uid
INNER JOIN
  tx_intranet_domain_model_mailentry as c ON c.uid=b.max 
WHERE a.deleted=0 AND a.disable=0
```

Comment: The last line should be: ORDER BY b.uid DESC

Answer (score 0):

This is because of in your subquery you are not selecting the timestamp that's why it is not recognize that and you order by is not working:

```
(SELECT x.uid,x.from_user,x.to_user,x.timestamp FROM mail as x ORDER BY x.uid DESC)
                                    ^^^ add here timestamp
```

Or you can do

```
(SELECT x.* FROM mail as x ORDER BY x.uid DESC)
```

As you are selecting all the fields.

Well you can also use the join.

Comment: Hello, I had a mittle mistake in my example: uid and timestamp are both giving me the order. So it should mean b.uid DESC instead of timestamp. But still the problem is: the GROUP BY is getting first, after that the ORDER BY follows so it does not bring me the right result. Any idea?

Comment: @dohomi Remove the order by from the subquery. you are using it twice. no need of that.

Comment: with or without removing, it doesn't affect my result. But I will clean up, but still on the search for the right query

Comment: @dohomi can you elaborate your problem much more.

Comment: I was reading somewhere to use a subquery with MAX(uid) but this was not working in my example. Could someone give me an example inside this example?